# Sideloading to new Outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

With the new Outlook update, how can I sideload my add-in into Outlook? The "Customize Add-in" button is no longer there and clicking into "Manage your Apps" doesn't have an option to sideload my own add-in.

This doc is also a bit outdated

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/sideload-outlook-add-ins-for-testing?tabs=windows

Comment: When you signed in into Outlook on Web, can you go to the following URL: https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?path=/options/manageapps . Do you see the "Add-ins for Outlook" form on the top of the Outlook explorer interface? Can you go to "My add-ins" and see "Custom add-ins" section? Can you see other sections, for example "Admin managed"?

Comment: Yep, I do see that, and I am able to sideload it to Outlook for the Web now. However, I would also need to be able to sideload to the Desktop version of Outlook. Previously, sideloading it to the Web version would also enable it on the desktop version, but it seems like that is no longer the case

Comment: When you sideload the add-on it will be loaded into all Outlook clients with your account. So, sideloading on the Web Outlook will add the add-on to Outlook Desktop on your Windows or Mac. Please keep in mind it may not appear right away on Desktop versions, as there is caching time depend on your Exchange environment settings.

Comment: When sideloading, I see the add-in working as expected in the Web version of Outlook; and clicking on the button opens the add-in as expected. However, while I see it in the Windows Desktop version of Outlook with the icon and name, clicking it doesn't open the add-in.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot comment on this, but can confirm I had similar behavior you have described; in my case, the add-on invoke the task pane, but the task pane displayed the error that add-on was not available, even thow the server was running and web version worked as expected. It went away after a few hours. At this point, I didn't investigate any thurther.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't even get the task pane to open up. By going away, did you mean the error? Or the task pane functionality?

Comment: I meant the add-on started to work properly on Outlook Desktop after some time. The error went away on it's own.

Comment: I will try to load it and just wait a bit then. Thank you!